# quick_exit() not available

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, mingw-w64

I was writing a multi-threading code and I was thought of using a quick_exit function to terminate my program without resource clean-up.
#include
#include
#include         // std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include
#include

```
using namespace std;
static void pause_thread(int n)
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(n));
  std::cout << "pause of " << n << " seconds ended\n";
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Spawning and detaching 3 threads...\n";
  std::thread (pause_thread,5).detach();
  std::thread (pause_thread,8).detach();
  std::thread (pause_thread,9).detach();
  std::cout << "Done spawning threads.\n";

  std::cout << "(the main thread will now pause for 2 seconds)\n";
  // give the detached threads time to finish (but not guaranteed!):
  pause_thread(2);
  quick_exit(0); //here is the problem,was this a problem?
  return 0;
}
```

compiling using GCC 5.3.0 and the command i have used

`g++ -std=c++11 practise.cpp -lpthread`

thread model:posix

Am I missing anything, I opened the header file of `cstdlib` and I see `quick_exit` is there.

```
C:\Program Files\mingw64>g++ -std=c++11 pracrise.cpp -lpthread
pracrise.cpp: In function 'int main()':
pracrise.cpp:25:15: error: 'quick_exit' was not declared in this scope
   quick_exit(0);
               ^
```

Comment: Which gcc version do you have exactly? BTW: Rather use the `-pthread` flag for compiling and linking.

Comment: gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.3.0

Comment: Sorry I didn't spot that in your question immediately.

Comment: Are you sure you can use `-lptrhead` on MinGW? http://mingw.org/wiki/pthreads_library

Comment: Yes i am sure previously i did some std::asyn functionalities with this GCC, and also i done some thread code too the problem is with the quick_exit() i can't understand what went wrong

Comment: Mingw-w64 is surely the problem here.  You'll have to look in your cstdlib header file.  The (dated) copy I have requires #defining _GLIBCXX_HAVE_QUICK_EXIT.  You are probably using the Microsoft CRT, it did not have quick_exit() available until the VS2015 release.

Comment: @HansPassant, just to be clear  _GLIBCXX_HAVE_QUICK_EXIT what this gaurd have to deal with Microsoft CRT.can you elaborate?