# Missing POSIX and std symbols using MSYS2/MINGW-64

Tags: c++, posix, porting, mingw-w64, msys2

I tried to port some C/C++ code from Linux to Windows. On Linux I am using GCC-10 for building, on Windows I am trying to use MSYS2/MINGW-64. I have never used MSYS2 before and I have few experience in porting Linux/POSIX code to windows.

Most of the (Qt) code is portable anway so I got non-trivial problems only in a few code lines. The following symbols turned out to be missing:

1. `on_exit()`
2. `O_SYNC` (used with `open()`)
3. `sync()`
4. `std::at_quick_exit()`

I'm not startled about 1. because it is not portable.

However 2. and 3. are POSIX symbols and 4. is part of the C++11 standard library. Since MSYS2 docs say it is POSIX and GCC compatible I would have expected these symbols to be defined.

Why are these symbols missing?
Is there a way to replace the missing features (maybe using calls to the Windows API)?

Comment: `On_exit` could be a quick comment like this one or an answer unto itself depending on the details. Windows has an annoying tendency to prefix POSIX stuff with an underscore. In the case of `on_exit`, they kind-of moved it and got [`_onexit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/onexit-onexit-m?view=msvc-160). But this still makes a bit of since because `on_exit` isn't POSIX. `atexit` is POSIX. But none of these functions really match up 1:1, so consult the documentation.

Comment: @user4581301 Any idea if MSYS2 possibly provides them in some weird way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're out of luck with 4.  Mostly out of luck with 2. You'll have to do a lot of re-writing. I'd ask a question about this one specifically. 3 `_flushall` might do what you need. [Consult the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/flushall?view=msvc-160) to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think MinGW ever claimed full POSIX compatibilty, so the lack of `O_SYNC` and `sync()` is to be expected.

`on_exit` has a standard alternative [`std::atexit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit).

Judging by the comments under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36825196/2752075), `at_quick_exit` (and `quick_exit` itself) aren't provided by `msvcrt.dll` (the old Microsoft C runtime that MINGW64 uses). You can switch to the [UCRT64 MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/), which uses a more modern C runtime (`ucrtbase.dll`) that does have those functions.

Comment: Well POSIX compatibility is what they wrote somewhere on their website. However after some more reading it seems you are right. They call it "mostly-POSIX-compliant" on this page: https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-introduction/

Comment: @Silicomancer I think they're talking about the shell, command-line utilities, apparent filesystem hierarchy, etc, not the compiler itself. They also mention that they have a Cygwin fork (and Cygwin strives to emulate POSIX), however you're not using it (that would be MSYS environment), and I'd avoid it.

Comment: Ok, I will try UCRT64 environment. Do you know if UCRT64 provides same packages as MINGW64 or could it happen that something is missing in UCRT64 (like pre-built Qt and pre-configured Qt Creator)?

Comment: @Silicomancer Check the list of packages to be sure. Also keep in mind that binaries compiled on UCRT64 won't work on Win 7 out of the box (the runtime needs to be installed separately I think).

Comment: Switching to UCRT64 solved the std::at_quick_exit issue. Appart from that I used _commit() instead of O_SYNC, std::atexit instead of on_exit() (but without using the exit code).